# Count amount of 3s in a series of numbers

Tags: c++, math

(This isn't homework)

I'm working on a practice question (https://train.nzoi.org.nz/problems/1207) - "count the number of 3's when printing the numbers from 1 to N". I haven't found any solution online and I was wondering what a more efficient way to answer this question is.

my solution is:

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int l;
    cin >> l;

    int c=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < (l + 1); i++)
    {   
        int j = i;
        while (j>0)
        {
            int tmp = j%10;
            if (tmp == 3) c++;
            j /= 10;
        }
    }

    cout << c << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

although this takes a long time on long numbers.
what is a more efficient way to solve this problem?

EDIT:
For clarification, This is trying to find all instances of 3 while counting from 0 => N
E.G: 13 => 2 occurances of 3

Comment: _"although this takes a long time on long numbers"_ How did you determine this? Even a 64-bit integer only has, like, 19 decimal places, and on any modern processor (embedded or otherwise) should take well under a second

Comment: What is a "long time"?

Comment: yesterday there was similar question with digit 4 instead of 3. Do the maths first: There is one number with digit 3 between 0 and 10. There are 10 numbers with 3 as second digit between 0 and 100, and 10 numbers with 3 as first digit, one of them is 33, ie there are 19 in total. Same for three or more digits

Comment: @jarmod, longer then a second.

Comment: btw shorter variable names do not make your program run faster, but they make the code harder to read

Comment: @Human-Compiler i'm not too sure why it takes longer then a second, running this program with a number such as 2000000000000000, takes longer then a second (failing).

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 oop, my apologies, I will edit with easier to read variable names.

Comment: You presumably only need to iterate over the count of digits in the input number (and test if each digit == 3), not over the actual value of the input number.

Comment: @Unkwn, in all likelihood `2000000000000000` won't fit in an `int`.

Comment: ... and this is a slight variation compared to the question i was refering to. Here the tasks ask for number of times the digit appears, not amount of numbers that have the digit, so my example was wrong, correct result for 100 is 20 not 19

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 -- whoops, careless. I've deleted my comment.

Comment: You might want to specify what your program needs to calculate explicitly. Having it available through a link is not good - people won't click it. Which may lead to confusion.

Comment: Assuming `int` is 32-bit, `2000000000000000` is a signed int overflow. If this number goes negative, you're in UB land and it might run for a very long time

Comment: @anatolyg I will keep this in mind for future reference, thanks.

Comment: @Human-Compiler I'm still quite new to CPP, will typing my input as a int, hinder my performance somehow?

Comment: @Unkwn: No, humans are slower than the slowest computer. But an `int` has a limited range, often about 2 billion.

Comment: @Unkwn, it doesn't hinder your performance if the inputed value can be stored in an `int` variable, if not all bets are off.

Comment: @Unkwn for a better assessment post a MRE, variables `i`, `j` and `c` are undefiend in your code.

Comment: @anastaciu oops, I tried to rename the variables for easier understanding throught the stackoverflow text editor. I have reverted it should work now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a good use-case for recursion. Call your function `f(n)` (short name because I'm going to use math notation below). Then calculate f(n) by something like f(a) + f(b) + ... when all of the numbers a, b, ... are much smaller than n.

I am only going to give ideas by examples, not code. I hope this will be complete enough to write code, and not too much, so the task remains interesting.

First of all:

```
f(0) = 0
f(1) = 0
f(2) = 0
f(3) = 1
f(4) = 1
...
f(9) = 1
f(10) = 1
```

---

Now calculate f(n) for n which are powers of 10:

```
f(10) = 1
f(100) = 20
f(1000) = 300
...
f(10^(n+1)) = 10 * f(10^n) + 10^n  (or something like that)
```

I hope I did it right. The idea is, for e.g. n = 1000, consider e.g. all 3-digit numbers with first digit 6. There are f(100) 3's in this list. The same for all other first digits, except for 3, where there are 100 more 3's.

---

Now consider an arbitrary `n`. Check its first digit; call it `d`. The list of all numbers smaller than `n` contains all possible numbers whose first digit is smaller than `d`, and some numbers whose first digit is exactly `d`. Now consider all these lists separately, and count 3's in them.

---

General advice: keep your "slow" code accessible at all times while you are writing your "fast" code. This way, it will be easy to test your code, and find unhandled cases, off-by-one bugs and such.